# Estimated Time for script Python ( with progress bar)

Tags: python

I have a Python script like this:

```
def foo():
     #code 

def bar():
     #code

def baz():
     #code 

if __name__ == '__main__':

     #code
```

the code above is a simple code used to scrape some sites and grab various informations, and in the main  I create a dataframe.

I need to know (when I launch the script) how much time has passed and how much time is left. I have read something about a progress bar **but please do not answer with:**   "Use

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    ...
```

".

I eventually need to know how to precisely implement the code to obtain a progress bar in my script. I wrote just an example code because there is no need to have the real code to add some bar (my problem is that I don't know where to insert the loop or something similar if using libraries like tqdm or progressbar)

thanks

Comment: "there is no need to have the real code to add some bar" How would you estimate the runtime behavior of unknown code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually need is to have an `iterable` within your functions, and then call `tqdm(iterable)`.

So, if your function is:

```
def foo():
    for i in range(10000):
        # code
```

Then you do apply the example you provided:

```
def foo():
    for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
        # code
```

or equivalent:

```
def foo():
    for i in trange(10000):
        # code
```

So if your functions depend on a loop of an iterable, you can just implement it easily. But if not, then you should see how you could add something like that. For example, you could create more functions to use them as steps:

```
def foo():
   for step in tqdm(range(3)):
       foo_step(step)

def foo_step(step):
    if step==0:
        # code step 0
    elif step==1:
        # code step 1
    elif step==2:
        # code step 2
    else:
        return -1
```

But this won't take into account that the steps could last different times. But if you already know or estimate how much they could last, you could do:

```
def foo():
   with tqdm(total=100) as pbar:
       for step in tqdm(range(3)):
           foo_step(step)

       def foo_step(step):
           if step==0:
               pbar.update(STEP_0_%_TIME)
               # code step 0
           elif step==1:
               pbar.update(STEP_1_%_TIME)
               # code step 1
           elif step==2:
               pbar.update(STEP_2_%_TIME)
               # code step 2
           else:
               return -1
```